# Reshape 1d array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hei Guys,
im pretty confused about this and don´t know how to solve it.
I receive an 1d array that looks like this.

```
$mitarbeiter = array();

$mitarbeiter[] = "Max,Mustermann,017154121245,EDV,Departmentdirector";

$mitarbeiter[] = "Markus,Mustermann,0147101454123,EDV";

$mitarbeiter[] = "Lisa,Tester,017312343223,Support";
```

The array will contain 50-100 $mitarbeiter.
I want to use the values as first name, last name, number and department which can have multiple values.
How can i make an 3d array out of it. Would it make sense to use one for my problem?
Do you have any idea how i can solve this.
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: just iterate on your array and just explode by comma on each element, and then assign it on another container, its your choice if you want to add a key name with it too

Comment: This data looks like it comes from a csv file. If so, php has functions to parse csv.

Comment: the data is from a txt file.
how do i add the key name?

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate your array in the loop and get value

```
$mitarbeiter = array();

$mitarbeiter[] = "Max,Mustermann,017154121245,EDV,Departmentdirector";

$mitarbeiter[] = "Markus,Mustermann,0147101454123,EDV";

$mitarbeiter[] = "Lisa,Tester,017312343223,Support";

if(!empty($mitarbeiter)){
    foreach($mitarbeiter as $row){
        $val = explode(',', $row);
        //e.g val[0] first name
        //e.g val[1] last name and so on, make sure key exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$mitarbeiter = array();

$mitarbeiter[] = "Max,Mustermann,017154121245,EDV,Departmentdirector";

$mitarbeiter[] = "Markus,Mustermann,0147101454123,EDV";

$mitarbeiter[] = "Lisa,Tester,017312343223,Support";

$mitarbeiter = array_map(function ($v) {
  return explode(',', $v);
}, $mitarbeiter);

print_r($mitarbeiter);
```